# Warning: Division by zero com datas

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

como posso fazer para calcular um intervalo de datas por exemplo: 24/08/2017 e 09/05/2017 e pegar a quantidade total de dias?

por exemplo o resultado dessa diferença teria que dar 106 dias de diferença de uma data para outra

codigo:

```
$data = $row['data'];
$data_inicio = $row['data_inicio'];

$now = time();
$date1 = date("Y-m-d", $now);

$time_inicial = geraTimestamp($date1);
$time_final = geraTimestamp($data);
$diferenca = $time_final - $time_inicial;

$dias = (int)floor($diferenca / (60 * 60 * 24));



$d2 = geraTimestamp($data_inicio);
$diff =  $time_inicial - $d2;

$diasC = (int)floor($diff / (60 * 60 * 24));


$conta = ($dias * 100) / $diasC;                                                                


$result = number_format($conta,2);
```

Comment: essa somatoria e o valor total em dias como eu falei no exemplo 24/08/2017 e 09/05/2017 o valor total em dias dessas datas e 106 dias. intendeu? voce vai somar a primeira data que e 09/05/2017 com 24/08/2017 e o valor que vai sair e 106 dias

Comment: como eu faco isso que eu quero você saberia me informar?

Comment: Já editei a resposta.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O erro acontece porquê você está utilizando `$diasC` como denominador. O valor desta variável é definido na linha anterior:

```
$diasC = (int) floor($diff / (60 * 60 * 24));
```

Ou seja, se a diferença entre as datas for inferior a um dia, essa divisão resultará em um valor entre 0 e 1. Utilizando `floor` e fazendo o *cast type* para `int`, o resultado será 0. Utilizar denominador 0 não é permitido. Ou você valida o valor desta variável para ser maior que zero ou você utiliza a solução abaixo.

### Solução

Se o objetivo é apenas obter a diferença entre datas, utilize a classe nativa [`DateTime`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/class.datetime.php). Ela possui um método chamado `diff` que calcula a diferença entre duas datas. Veja:

```
$data1 = new DateTime("2017-05-12");
$data2 = new DateTime("2017-05-09");

$diff = $data1->diff($data2);

echo $diff->format("Diferença de %y anos, %m meses e %d dias."), PHP_EOL;
```

A saída seria:

```
Diferença de 0 anos, 0 meses e 3 dias.
```

Mesmo que invertesse a ordem das datas, o resultado é o mesmo. Se isso for em confronto à alguma outra especificação da sua aplicação, tome cuidado.

> Veja funcionando no [Ideone](https://ideone.com/v9Y9Zn).

Se for necessário obter em dias corridos, não em meses e anos, basta formatar o resultado utilizando `%a`:

```
echo $diff->format("Diferença de %a dias corridos."), PHP_EOL;
```

> Veja funcionando no [Ideone](https://ideone.com/zcQqEY).

**Nota: Obtendo valor numérico**

Para obter apenas o valor numérico, basta fazer:

```
$diffInDays = (int) $diff->format("%a");
```

Comment: ela esta definida sim e a data final que vem do banco de dados esqueci de colocar ela aqui eu vo editar a pergunta

Comment: editei a pergunta

Comment: exatamente isso muito obrigado